# Wald General Relativity Exercice 4.5 - Derivation of Tensor Calculus Identity Relevant to "Effective Gravitational Stress Tensor"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

This is a lot of text so I apologise, its hard to pose this question concisely while still being clear.

In the text, Wald derives to second order deviation from flatness an expression for the "effective" stress tensor for the gravitational field, in terms of the Einstein tensor. He then claims that this is not to be taken too literally, since we can add to it any tensor of the form $\partial^c \partial^d U_{acbd}$, where U is quadratic in the metric pertubation has the symmetry properties $U_{acbd} = U_{[ac]bd} = U_{ac[bd]} = U_{bdac}$, without altering the primary characteristics of the constructed stress tensor: symmetry, being quadratic in the pertubation, and being conserved. In the exercices he asks the reader to expand on this:

> Let $T_{ab}$ be a symmetric conserved tensor field in Minkowski Spacetime. Show that there exists a tensor $U_{acbd}$ with [the above] symmetry properties, such that $T_{ab} = \partial^c \partial^d U_{acbd}$.

He also provides the following hint:

> For any vector field $v^a$ in Minkowski spacetime satisfying $\partial_{a} v^a = 0$, there exists an antisymmetric tensor field such that $v^a = \partial_b s^{ab}$. Use this result to show that $T_{ab} = \partial^c W_{cab}$ where W is antisymmetric in its first two indices. Use the fact $\partial^c W_{c[ab]} = 0$ to derive the desired result.

The derivation here is causing issues. My main idea is to treat $T_{ab}$ as being a set of 4 vectors, and applying the result to each - each individual (conserved) vector would have an antisymmetric 2-index tensor associated. Such a collection of 4 2-index tensors would form the 3-index one W, and the (anti)symmetry properties follow simply. This seems... sketchy - it doesn't feel quite legitimate to just decompose a tensor into a set of vectors - is this allowed? If not I am not sure how to apply the vector identity to this case with a tensor.

Additionally, I am clueless as to how to extend this to obtain the 4-index tensor U. My first thought was that you could note that $\partial^c W_{cab}$ is identical to $T_{ab}$ and thus has the necessary properties to apply the same process as above a second time. However, I realise that despite W having 3 indices, this construction is still only a 2 index tensor due to contraction, and thus would yield a 3-index tensor again rather than the needed 4-index one. It seems like there is no way to make progress here in constructing a 4-index tensor with this (obviously there is since its in a textbook and is therefore possible, but I am lost).

An additional side concern is the specification of Minkowski spacetime here, since the original purpose of this construction was in curved spacetime! Is it fair to replace the ordinary partial derivatives here with covariant ones, and call it a day? Or is this truly only valid in flat spacetime?

Edit: I have attempted this question further and still have no idea how to progress - it's probable I am missing something simple but I am utterly lost. A pointer in the right direction would be appreciated.